# How to determine column is Blob while migrating database

Tags: java, mysql, blob

I am trying to migrate data from one database to another using Java. All other data-types get migrated successfully except Blob type.

Here is how I am checking data-types and migrating them.

```
private String getValue(String value, String type, int i){
        StringBuilder columnValue = new StringBuilder("");
        if(type.equals("java.lang.String") || type.equals("java.sql.Timestamp") || type.equals("java.lang.Blob")){
            if(i== (columnNames.size()-1))
                columnValue.append("'"+value+"'");
```

Note : in `type` I am getting Blob as `[B`, I am aware of the fact that `Blob` is getting passed as `Bytes Array` so I tried to do check it as array as well , like this

```
type.getBytes().equals("byte[]")
```

I am unable to find out where I am doing wrong.

Comment: I think you'll need `java.sql.Blob` anyway

Comment: @Lucas: Many JDBC drivers return `byte[]` when you use `rs.getObject()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct solution depends on how you create the value for `type`. If you use `rs.getObject(col).getClass().getName()`, then this compare will work:

```
type.equals("[B")
```

You'll get the same result for `byte[].class.getName()`. To protect you against typos, I suggest that you pass the type as `Class<?>`. That allows you to check the type using `isAssignableFrom()`:

```
if( type.isAssignableFrom(String.class)
    || type.isAssignableFrom(java.sql.Timestamp.class)
    || type.isAssignableFrom(byte[].class)
) {
```

Comment: Yes you are right. 
checking `type.equals("[B")` did the trick.